# In the anime, how many girls did Itou Makoto sleep with and are they all emotionally tied?

Tags: school-days

Did Itou Makoto sleep with all the girls in the anime? And if so, did all those girls were affectionate towards Itou? I'm not sure if Itou really played dirty with all the girls. I'm too slow with this kind of thing and I just happened to watch this anime because of Kotonoha.

Comment: Related? https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/how-many-endings-are-there-in-the-school-days-visual-novel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer refers to the anime series only:

No, not all of them; remember, he was in a class wherein about half of all the 50 or so students were female. The only girls Makoto became intimate with were: Kotonoha Katsura, Sekai Saionji, Setsuna Kiyoura, Hikari Kuroda, Otome Katou, Minami Obuchi, Natsumi Koizumi and Kumi Mori.

And out of all of those, it was really only Kotonoha and Sekai who were affectionate towards him. The others were only interested in him for carnal pleasures or some sort of manipulation.

Comment: It's a reasonable assumption to make, considering how many girls were keen on sleeping with the lucky bastard! But in the end, *School Days* takes an extremely cynical and pessimistic view about love, sex and interpersonal relations...

Comment: Wait Makoto had sex with all of them EXCEPT Kotonoha?

Comment: 'And out of all of those, it was really only Kotonoha and Sekai who were affectionate towards him.' --> I think this is wrong too. Otome liked Makoto since middle school or something, iirc.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Meir Illumination's answer is incorrect for 2 reasons, but Meir Illumination hasn't been around for a year, so:

1. Actually in the anime, Makoto did not have sex with Kotonoha.
2. 'And out of all of those, it was really only Kotonoha and Sekai who were affectionate towards him.' --> I think this is wrong too. Otome liked Makoto since middle school or something, iirc.

Makoto had sex with

1. Sekai Saionji: Makoto's seatmate
2. Setsuna Kiyoura: Sekai's 'friend' (meaning that they were friends at least up to the point Makoto cheated on Sekai with Setsuna)
3. Hikari Kuroda: Sekai's 'friend' (meaning that they were friends at least up to the point Makoto cheated on Sekai with Setsuna)
4. Otome Katou: who knew Makoto in middle school
5. 5-8. and then the ['trio' Minami Obuchi, Natsumi Koizumi and Kumi Mori](https://overflow.fandom.com/wiki/Trio)

From the [fandom](https://overflow.fandom.com/wiki/Trio):

> There is a trio of 3 girls who are Otome's friend and serve as minor characters.

> They generally bully Kotonoha for no reason other than their jealousy of her beauty and breast size and make up assumptions about her, such as her dating Makoto for money or lying about Makoto being her boyfriend.

> In Episode 11, they are curious about "how good" Makoto is and come over to his apartment for a foursome between them. They're apparently satisfied with his performance, exhibiting disappoint at having to avoid him after Sekai's announcement.